# listing files in Google Cloud Bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

So to view all files in a GCP bucket we have a hook

```
 bucket = 'bucket-name'
 hook = GoogleCloudStorageHook(google_cloud_storage_conn_id='ListenerScience',
                                  delegate_to=None)
list_of_files = hook.list(bucket)
```

But if I wanted to view files inside a folder in the bucket like

```
'bucket-name/FolderOne/SubFolder'
```

I get an error saying not a directory. Is there a simple way to view all the files inside folders of bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set the [prefix](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcs_hook.py#L299) option to the `list` method, e.g. something like:

```
list_of_files = hook.list(bucket, prefix='FolderOne/SubFolder')
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I run the above code I get 'GoogleCloudStorageHook' object has no attribute 'list'. Do you have an idea how to solve this? @jterrace

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to make much sense, since that's the method you're calling in your code.